# conductor of a map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A\to R$ be a ring homomorphism between two commutative rings with unity. I want to know what is it meant by conductor of a map $A\to R$. Is it the annhilator in $A$ of the $R$-module $R/A$?

In Eisenbud (Commutative algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry) page 272 this is defined for the normalisation map of a Noetherian domain. For an arbitrary map is it defined the above way?

Also where can I found the conductor ideal of such map (in commutative algebra context).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.12/share/doc/Macaulay2/IntegralClosure/html/_conductor.html